# Draw outline around string without artifacts in .NET

Tags: .net, graphics, drawing

I have written a script, which renders text into an image in Powershell.

These should be the relevant pieces of code:

```
$fontFamily = new-object System.Drawing.FontFamily "Arial"
$stringFormat = new-object System.Drawing.StringFormat
$fontSize = 50

# background brush, transparent
$brushBg = [System.Drawing.Brushes]::Black
# foreground brush
$colorFg = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(105, 160, 215)
$colorOutline = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
$brushFg = new-object System.Drawing.SolidBrush($colorFg)

$path = new-object System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
$path.AddString("sometext", $fontFamily, [int]([System.Windows.FontStyle]::Regular), ([float] $fontSize), (new-object System.Drawing.Point 0, 0), $stringFormat)

# ...
# magically get some graphics context to draw on
# ....

# draw the outline in white
$pen = new-object System.Drawing.Pen($colorOutline, 12)
$graphics.DrawPath($pen, $path)
$pen.Dispose()

# draw the text itself in blue
$graphics.FillPath($brushFg, $path)

...
```

Now the problem is that I get ugly artifacts from the DrawPath when I make the outline too wide as can be seen in the following image.

[image: Artifacts from DrawPath on the w]

How to avoid them?

Sandro

Comment: That makes complete sense and works like a charm! If you post it as an answer, I am happy to give you credit for it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These spikes are caused by the sharp transitions in the W shape.  A side-effect of the pen's MiterLimit.  Changing the [Pen.LineJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.linejoin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is usually best, you get rid of these miter artifacts by choosing Bevel or Round.